# Playing audio file on click again before it's finished playing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a soundboard-type website that is pretty simple (this is actually my first project). The premise is that a user loads the page, clicks a button, and a sound plays.

The issue I'm having is that if a user clicks button "A", in the x amount of time it takes to play the sound for button "A", clicking button "A" does not initiate another instance of its sound.

So if the sound for button "A" takes 1 second to play and the user clicks 10 times within 1 second, the sound for button "A" only plays once instead of 10 times.

Not sure if this link works...but this is a link to the fiddle? Beware, no audio is attached to the fiddle so sound won't actually play when you click the buttons.
https://jsfiddle.net/pmqr9L0s/

This is what my js looks like so far though:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var kickBass1 = new Audio("audio/kickbass1.mp3");
    $(".kickbass1").click(function(){
        kickBass1.play();
    });

    var hihat1 = new Audio("audio/hihat1.mp3");
    $(".hihat1").click(function(){
        hihat1.play();
    });

    var snare1 = new Audio("audio/snare1.mp3");
    $(".snare1").click(function(){
        snare1.play();
    });

    //add record feature later?
    var record = function(){
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try moving your variables inside your click handlers, so that you create a new `Audio` element every time one of your buttons is clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function(){        
    $(".kickbass1").click(function(){
        var kickBass1 = new Audio("audio/kickbass1.mp3");
        kickBass1.play();
    });    

    $(".hihat1").click(function(){
        var hihat1 = new Audio("audio/hihat1.mp3");
        hihat1.play();
    });    

    $(".snare1").click(function(){
        var snare1 = new Audio("audio/snare1.mp3");
        snare1.play();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! A little off topic, but while I'm noticing no issues on a desktop, but when I open my site on mobile it seems like there's a bit of a delay between clicking on the button and the audio playing -- is that a byproduct of the way I'm playing the audio file?

Comment: Probably depends on many different factors, including the memory and processor on your phone, and how it is loaded with javascript, but I wouldn't imagine that difference has anything to do with the way you wrote your code. If you are targeting mobile, it may be better to make a native app for this sort of application. I'm sure the phone's native API for loading and playing sounds is more efficient than a mobile browser loading and playing sounds via JS.